# Player swinging with a rope, How do I calculate the tension of the rope to apply on the player? (Monogame)

Tags: c#, game-physics, monogame

This is my first time asking a question here so sorry if I didn't say everything that was needed, feel free to ask for more info if you need it.

Basically, I am creating a player character that moves around using acceleration like so:

```
velocity.X += movingDir * acceleration - friction * velocity.X;
velocity.Y += gravityScale * gravityVector //Vector2(0,9.81f * gravityScale)
if (normalMouvement)
    velocity.X = Math.Clamp(velocity.X, -maxSpeed, maxSpeed);
```

I want to make the player attached to a rope when he presses A, then swing around it until he releases A. The player already has a starting velocity that will change along the rope swing (so for example, if I press left when swinging to the right, I'll swing slower). The position of where the rope is attached to is already defined.

[image: what I mean] (I know this is high level art wow)

I've tried doing this after reading [this article](https://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Tension-in-Physics):

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(Keys.A))
        distanceToGrapplingPoint = (Platformer.Map.data.grapplingPoints[0].Pos - Pos).Length();
if (Input.GetKey(Keys.A))
        Swing();
//this is in the Update Method

private void Swing()
    {
        Vector2 distance = Vector2.Normalize(Platformer.Map.data.grapplingPoints[0].Pos - Pos) * distanceToGrapplingPoint;
        
        Vector2 gravityTension = -Vector2.Normalize(distance) * gravityVector.Y * gravityScale * distance.Y / distance.Length();
        Vector2 centripetalForce = distance * gravityVector.Y * gravityScale * (velocity / distance.Length()) * (velocity / distance.Length());
        
        Vector2 totalTension = gravityTension + centripetalForce;
        
        velocity += totalTension;
    }
```

but my player just flies right into the grappling point. I don't want to just set the position of the player and call it a day but actually calculate the tension of the rope to make the code more modular.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Are you doing a rope or a rigid fixed distance?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a lot of redundancy with respect to `Normalize()` and `Length()`

`distanceToGrapplingPoint` is the distance to be maintained from the pivot. This value is needed because friction is in play:

To maintain a circular motion path, the applied force must be a constant squared ratio between X and Y, X^2 + Y^2 = `distanceToGrapplingPoint`, the application of friction on the X axis unbalances this ratio, causing the Y value to reduce in magnitude in kind, thus making the pendulum shorter on each pass.

---

Let us look at 90 degree steps around a unit circle, in math coordinates (y+, 0 degree start = Right):

(1,0)->(0,1)->(-1,0)->(0,-1)

Now substitute X for 1 and look at the pattern:

(X,0)->(0,X)->(-X,0)->(0,-X)

Note how X becomes Y then becomes X again.

Now if X is reduced by friction(only on the fraction of the X when it is the X component) When the friction reduced value becomes the Y value, Y is restricted to match the X value.

For the above reason, the solution presented in the following code applies a correction step to maintain the circular path. The result is close to being physically accurate, in games we call that close enough.

---

To get truly accurate results; the pendulum needs its own velocity(beyond the scope of this answer.)

We will define `angleToGrapplingPoint` as the direction unit vector, in your code:`Vector2.Normalize(distance)`

Note: Centripetal Force does not exist, it is an external restriction by the rope stated to counter Newton's 1st law of motion: an object in motion will continue that motion unless acted upon by an outside force, in this case, tension.

```
private void Swing()
    {
        Vector2 angleToGrapplingPoint = Vector2.Normalize(Platformer.Map.data.grapplingPoints[0].Pos - Pos);
        
        // enforce the distance constraint 
        // for fixed pole not rope for 1-179 degree angles
        Pos = angleToGrapplingPoint * distanceToGrapplingPoint;

        // subtract the gravity component is will be adjusted for tension and 
        //  added back in the next line
        Velocity -= gravityVector.Y * gravityScale; 
        
        // Apply the tension to gravity by adding an X component while diminishing the Y component(depending on angle)
        Velocity += gravityVector.Y * gravityScale * angleToGrapplingPoint;


        // Add the constraint to keep in a circle x*x + y*y = r*r
        // or Cos^2(x) + Sin^2(y) * gravity + velocity ~=  distanceToGrapplingPoint;
        // This code limits the movement to the bounds of the circle
        Velocity -= angleToGrapplingPoint * angleToGrapplingPoint gravityVector.Y * gravityScale;
    }
```

This code may not be 100% physically accurate, but it should be close.